# TTS and STT while driving - Samsung G3 (BlueTooth)

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, text-to-speech

I have a few cell phones, and have never had a problem with TTS/STT with my 2012 Rio until I got a Samsung S3. My Rio has build in blue tooth.

My HTC WP7, iPhone, and BlackBerry read messages out loud to me in my cars built in blue-tooth, and let me talk back to re-send the message.

With Android, it just beeps.

What I expected (and what I got from my other phones):

```
Car: New text message from "so and So". Do you want to read, or ignore.
me: read.
Car: Reads message.
Car: Do you want to reply, or cancel?
me: Reply
Car: [beep]
Me: say what I want.
car: repeats what I've said to verify
Me: Send
done.
```

This works on all my other phones without the need to install other software.

Any thoughts on how to get this working on my Samsung S3?